# Why smooth function space is separable under the Holder norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $C^\infty(R^d)$ be the space of infinite order differentiable function space.
As well known that $C^\infty(R^d)$ is not separable under uniform norm
$$
\|f\|=\sup_{x\in R^d}|f(x)|.
$$
However, it seems that $C^\infty(R^d)$ is separable under Hölder norm
$$
\|f\|_\alpha=\sup_{x\in R^d}|f(x)|+\sup_{x,y\in R^d,x\ne y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha}.
$$
I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: What exactly is the space $C^\infty$? Without further assumptions, the norm could be infinite on some elements of this space.

Comment: I am sorry that I forgot to set the space C^\infty(R^d) with the bounded property.